# Extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ is always abelian extension?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ is always abelian extension ?

I know the number of $p$-extension degree **abelian** extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ is $p+1$ from class field theory,but what about $p$-extension degree extension of $\Bbb Q_p$?

Comment: Think of $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p})$.

Comment: I think it is not Galois because normality does not hold. Are there a case in which Galois group is not abelian group ?

Comment: Indeed, the extension is not Galois. For your question, remember that groups of prime order are always cyclic.

Comment: Note that (over any field), a *Galois* extension of prime degree is automatically abelian. But look at @Mindlack's example and think of roots of unity for non-Galois field extensions of degree $p>2$. (For $p=2$ several things are special, there are seven extensions and they're all abelian like any quadratic extension.)

Comment: My question changed to new one, that is ,' Galois extension over Qp is always abelian?'. If it is not suitable for comment space, I will post new question.

Comment: Well, what about the Galois closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p})$?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, it might not always be abelian.

However, it will always be solvable, thanks to the theory of [higher ramification groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_group) (see e.g. [Local Fields](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-5673-9) by Serre):

The Galois group $G$ of any (finite) Galois extension $L/K$ of local fields admits a filtration $G = G_{-1} \supseteq G_0 \supseteq G_1 \supseteq G_2 \supseteq \cdots$ of **normal** subgroups (in $G$), where:

- $G_0$ corresponds to the maximal unramified subextension $K^{nr}/K$ of $L/K$, so $G_{-1}/G_0$ is cyclic.
- $G_0 / G_1$ corresponds to the maximal tamely ramified subextension $K^t/K^{nr}$ of $L/K^{nr}$, so $G_0/G_1$ is cyclic with order coprime to $p$.
- $G_n / G_{n+1}$ is a product of cyclic groups of order $p$ for $n \ge 1$.

So in particular each subquotient $G_n / G_{n+1}$ is cyclic, which is the next best thing after $G$ being abelian.